# Winning Loop Connect 4

Tags: java, homework, swing, connect-four

I am writing a fully functional single player Connect 4 game. I am working on the second player and the while loop that tells the player who won.

GUI

```
package lab7; 



import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUIClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("CSE 115 Connect 4");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout myGrid = new GridLayout(7, 6);
        JPanel panel;
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(myGrid);
        f.setLayout(myGrid);

        f.pack();

        ArrayList<JButton> col_button = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for (Integer i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            JButton b = new JButton("Col " + i.toString());
            col_button.add(b);
            f.add(b);
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<JLabel>> col_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<JLabel>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            col_list.add(new ArrayList<JLabel>());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
        {


            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/blank.png"));
            //System.out.println(label.getIcon().toString())
            col_list.get(i % 7).add(label);
            f.add(label);
        }
        GameClass gc = new GameClass(col_list);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            col_button.get(i).addActionListener(new ColButton(col_list.get(i)));
        }

        f.pack();

    }

    ImageIcon whiteCircle = new ImageIcon("blank.png");
}
```

that contains all of the graphical interface behind my code, as you might have guessed I used Java and Eclipse.

This is my game class where my second player is going to be, and I also assume my winning loop will be here.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GameClass{

    public GameClass(ArrayList<ArrayList<JLabel>> col_list)
    {

    }
}
```

finally this is my column class which contains the 1st player and all the buttons.

```
package lab7;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ColButton implements ActionListener {

    private ArrayList<JLabel> _column;
    private GameClass _game;

    public ColButton(ArrayList<JLabel> c)
    {
        _column = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = _column.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            JLabel l = _column.get(i);
            if(l.getIcon().toString().equals("images/blank.png"))
            {
                l.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/red.png"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What do you think?  Any suggestions on how to get get going for the second part? I am working on the 2<sup>nd</sup> player but I have run into some setbacks.

Comment: Great article on game loop implementation here: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ Also, your question is too generic. Try doing an actual game loop implementation, and then ask a more punctual question, if you have issues.

Comment: thanks for the article shivan dragon, I will get with it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a Swing application would be written using a Model-View-Controller pattern to split the responsibilities:

- The Model would be a data structure to represent the game state.  It could, for example, consist of an `ConnectFourBoard` class that holds a two-dimensional array of chips in the board.
- The View would be the Swing UI code
- The Controller acts as the glue between the Model and View.  It handles actions triggered by the View, and notifies the View when the Model has changed.

Here, I see View and Controller code, commingled.  However, I don't see any Model code.  In fact, in `ColButton.actionPerformed()`, it appears that the lack of a Model is causing you some difficulty: you're resorting to determining the model state by parsing the icon name out of the view.

Without a Model, you are no doubt going to have a difficult time examining the model state to determine the winner.

Comment: I thought of what you said, and I decided to create a Volatile Boolean Loop and so far so good, I have not run into any trouble for now, at least. I'll show you the final product.

Comment: Feel free to [post a new question with the revised code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).